# Non-Angular Page + Protractor: sendKeys to date input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, datepicker, protractor

I'm trying to test validation on a non-Angular page, which requires an expiry date for a message, of which I'm using jQuery's datepicker.

[image]

In Chrome's console, I can simply pass through the value for the input field:

```
$('#expiry_datepicker').val("26-Apr-16")
```

So I thought I'd be able to send through that same value in Protractor:

```
// Page Object
this.expiryDatePicker = dvr.findElement(by.css('#expiry_datepicker'));

// Spec File
page.expiryDatePicker.sendKeys( '29-Apr-2016' );
```

However, that doesn't work. I then tried to click on the input field and then tried to click the element `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day')` but no luck with that either.

Anyone have ideas about being able to drive Selenium to select the date?

Comment: What is the issue that you find with this.expiryDatePicker = dvr.findElement(by.css('#expiry_datepicker'));

Comment: No issue with the calendar per se, but .sendKeys(date) doesn't work and validation is thrown regarding me passing through a valid date.

Comment: doesn't work means?? Send the error

Comment: Throws validation error. "Sorry, you must select an expiry date before you send your message."

Comment: mmmm..sendkeys doesn't enter anything? and gives no error on sendkeys code line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through [`executeScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

```
dvr.executeScript("arguments[0].val(arguments[1]);", page.expiryDatePicker.getWebElement(), "26-Apr-16");
```